# Getting only the symbol out of a hash in ruby

Tags: ruby

Given I have a hash like this in ruby

```
MyHash = { 
  :item1 => { :key1 => :value1, .... },
  :item2 => { :key1 => :value1, .... },
  ...
}
```

When calling `MyHash[:item1]` I get the full object. How can I only get the `:item1` symbol instead?

Comment: I'm a little confused. If you already have `:item1` to call `MyHash.[]` with, why would you want to get it again?

Comment: You are calling `MyHash[:item1]`, so you already have `:item1`. The question is a bit confusing. Can you try to explain what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: `MyHash.keys` gives you all of the hash's keys, if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: @Martin: if you make a question you should be ready to give some feedback and not leaving people in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the keys only, you can do it like this

```
MyHash.each_key do |key|
  puts key
end

# Output
item1
item2
...
```

Comment: it's unlikely a `each` method (which work by doing side-effects) will be useful...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Hash#keys](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-keys), e.g. `MyHash.keys.first`.